# Solving the SVM Dual Problem

Tags: optimization, svm

This toy problem was just thought of by me to get an better intuition for the SVM algorithm. Assume the following optimization problem:

$$
L(w, b, \alpha)=\frac{1}{2}||w||^2 - \sum_{i}\alpha_i[y_i(\langle w, x_i\rangle)+b)-1]
$$

This is the objective function of a SVM problem. To find the boundary that solves a given Classification problem, we have to solve

$$
\underset{w, b}{\mathrm{argmin}} \underset{\alpha}{\mathrm{argmax}}=\frac{1}{2}||w||^2 - \sum_{i}\alpha_i[y_i(\langle w, x_i\rangle)+b)-1]
$$

To find a decision boundary that is able to correctly classify data points.
I tried a very simple problem with two points $x_1 = [1, 1]$, $x_2 = [2, 3]$ and $y_1 =-1$, $y_2=1$. Taking the partial derivative for each variable, I was able to find the correct solution. Now, this objective function can be further simplified by plugging in the optimal values for $w$ and $b$:

$$
 \underset{\alpha}{\mathrm{argmax}}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i}\sum_j \alpha_i \alpha_j y_i y_j \langle x_i, x_j \rangle + \sum_i \alpha_i
$$

$$
s.t.\sum_i \alpha_iy_i=0
$$

I tried to solve the problem the same way, taking the partial derivative of each $\alpha$, setting to zero and try to solve it.
However, this will not give me any solution, I arrive at $a_1 = 7$ and $a_2 = 15$ which does not satisfy the constraint. I read that this is an quadratic optim. problem, and thus needs a different approach. If this is true, why was I able to solve the first opt. problem?

Comment: Hi, can you clarify, how did you use the constraint in the second problem when arriving at your solution?

Comment: Well, to be honest I didn't use the constraint while solving for alpha, just in the end to check if the alphas would satisfy the constraint. I am quite unfamiliar with this kind of optimization problem.

Comment: Ah, well of course that's going to be a problem! :) But really, you should think of this as an invitation to the beautiful world of Constrained Optimization, which I promise you is way more exciting than the unconstrained variety. Have you heard of Lagrange Multipliers?

Comment: Indeed I have, and If I understood correctly the alphas are nothing different than the Lagrangian Multipliers.

Comment: Oh I see, I read your question too quickly. Quadratic programs are not solvable in closed form generally, though in this case since you have a single constraint you may be able to attack it by writing $\alpha_N = -\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \alpha_iy_i}{y_N}$ and treating the problem as unconstrained, or something like that.